# recordreader for single line

Tags: java, hadoop

I wanted to modify recordreader a bit. So first, I wanted to see how a recordreader works for a single line. I tried to read a customized readrecorder.

```
        @Override
        public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            boolean returnValue =  lineRecord.nextKeyValue();
            value.clear();
             if (key == null) {
                key = new IntWritable();
            }
            key.set(countKey++);
            if (value == null) {
                value = new Text();
            }
            value = lineRecord.getCurrentValue();

            if(value != null)
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
```

I tried another code also.

```
        @Override
        public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            boolean returnValue =  lineRecord.nextKeyValue();
            value.clear();
             if (key == null) {
                key = new IntWritable();
            }
            key.set(countKey++);
            if (value == null) {
                value = new Text();
            }
            value = lineRecord.getCurrentValue();
            return returnValue;
        }
```

I did not change any other function. To both of them, when I give a two line input, I only get the first line to the mapper. I am not understanding what the mistake is. I am sorry if this is a very basic question but I have just started coding in hadoop and i got stuck up at this point. Thanks in advance.

Modification I want to do: I want do a multiword count. Count pair of words in certain distance(say 2). So there can be words which are across lines which are 2 words apart. So what I wanted was to include  words (say 2) from the previous line in each of the next line. I planned to do this in recordreader as it is just appending two strings to a string and I can store what I have seen the previous time.

Comment: what modification you have to do with recordreader?